# I want to get the data form form mysql table where data match with right side or not

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT a.*,b.clientId,c.partner_name, d.seo 
FROM project_estimate_detail as a,
    project as b,
    partner as c,
    projection as d 
WHERE a.project_cat_id = 5 and 
      a.project_id = b.id and 
      b.clientId = c.id and 
      c.status =1 and c.id = d.client_id 
GROUP BY(c.partner_name)
```

`in c.id = d.client_id` .. I want all row form c.id who match with or do not match `d.client_id`

Comment: Thanks bro @Sal00m.....but plss give me the ans ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

But to do that you should change to using explicit join syntax:-

```
SELECT a.*, b.clientId, c.partner_name, d.seo 
FROM project_estimate_detail as a,
INNER JOIN project as b ON a.project_id = b.id
INNER JOIN partner as c ON b.clientId = c.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN projection as d ON c.id = d.client_id 
WHERE a.project_cat_id = 5 
AND c.status =1 
GROUP BY(c.partner_name)
```

Note that I suspect this will not give you the results you want. You are grouping by _partner_name_ so you will get one row returned per *partner_name* . As I assume that a single partner name will have multiple clients and they can have multiple estimates you will have one rows details from  _project_estimate_detail_ and  *project* returned for each _partner_name_ ; which rows details is not determined and likely to be effectively random.

Comment: No problem, but suspect you will need to modify it to sort the grouping of rows.

Comment: What about the estimate details? In general I try and mention all the non aggregate columns in the SELECT, which at least keeps it in line with SQL standards.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you want to join several tables by one common atribute ID. In my oppinion you should use a LEFT JOIN.http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

See the differences between JOINS here and decide what is better for you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: My answer was first and correct, I've just didn't made the work for you... :(